# Gratient Module how can i print text in the same line

Tags: python

I'm trying to use gratient module but I need help

when I set this code:

```
import gratient

a = gratient.green("[1]")
ab = gratient.red("Private Tool")
print(a, ab)
```

The above code prints the text but in different lines, how can I print it in the same line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import gratient

a = gratient.green("[1]")
ab = gratient.red("Private Tool")
print((a + ab).replace("\n", " "))
```

This answer is not valid if you have a dedicated \n inside a or ab

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the string "a" has a "\n" at the end ("b" as well too). Try using rstrip:

```
print(a.rstrip("\n"), ab.rstrip("\n"))
```